# How to reverse a power series for any given function

Tags: calculus, power-series

If we are given a power series such as
$$
    \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots +\frac{x^n}{n!} + \ldots
$$
What techniques can we use besides guess and check to find out which function this is an expansion of.

I feel that this must involve $e^x$ in some way since $e^x$ expanded in powers of $x$ is
$$
    1 + x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots +\frac{x^n}{n!} + \ldots
$$
except that $1 + x$ is missing in this case.
Are there any techniques which don't involve guess and check?

Comment: then its just e^x - x - 1

Comment: you have to remember that an expansion is just an equivalent expression. so if e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3!...... subtract 1+x from both sides to obtain your function

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as [series reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html).

Just write $$x=\sum_{i=1}^p a_i y^{i/2}$$ and follow the method.

$$y=\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} $$ would lead to
$$y=\frac{1}{2} a_1^2 y+\left(\frac{a_1^3}{6}+a_2 a_1\right) y^{3/2}+\frac{1}{24}
   \left(a_1^4+12 a_2 a_1^2+24 a_3 a_1+12 a_2^2\right)
   y^2+\cdots$$ Identify the coefficients (one at the time).

Using the binomial theorem, for more terms, you would get
$$x=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{3}+\frac{y^{3/2}}{9 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{2
   y^2}{135}+\frac{y^{5/2}}{540 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{4 y^3}{8505}-\frac{139
   y^{7/2}}{340200 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{2 y^4}{25515}+O\left(y^{9/2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "How to REVERSE a power series" ?

Do you mean finding the fonction itself or the inverse function ?

For example :

$$
    y(x)=\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots +\frac{x^n}{n!} + \ldots \tag 1
$$
$$y(x)=e^x-1-x$$
$$x(y)=-\text{W}\big(-e^{-y-1}\big)-y-1$$
W is the LambertW function.

If the question is to identify a function from its infinite series, there is no general method.

A common method is to compare the series with a lot of series expansion of known functions. This is what you did when you compared with the series expansion of $e^x$.

Another method consists in deriving a differential equation from the series and solving the differential equation. For example  with the series $(1)$ :

$$
    y'(x)=\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots $$
$$y'(x)=x+y(x)$$
Solving this first order linear ODE leads to the general solution : $\quad y(x)=c\:e^x-x-1$

With the condition $y(0)=0 \quad\to\quad 0=c\:e^0-0-1=c-1\quad\to\quad c=1$
$$y(x)=e^x-x-1$$